# How do I get the concrete name (e.g. "<module_name>"."<class_name">) of a class reference in Python?

Tags: python, class

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_concrete_name_of_class(klass):
"""Given a class return the concrete name of the class.

klass - The reference to the class we're interested in.
"""

# TODO: How do I check that klass is actually a class?
# even better would be determine if it's old style vs new style
# at the same time and handle things differently below.

# The str of a newstyle class is "<class 'django.forms.CharField'>"
# so we search for the single quotes, and grab everything inside it,
# giving us "django.forms.CharField"
matches = re.search(r"'(.+)'", str(klass))
if matches:
    return matches.group(1)

# Old style's classes' str is the concrete class name.
return str(klass)
```

So this works just fine, but it seems pretty hackish to have to do a regex search on the string of the class.  Note that I cannot just do `klass().__class__.__name__` (can't deal with args, etc.).

Also, does anyone know how to accomplish the TODO (check if `klass` is a class and whether its oldstyle vs new style)?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Based on the comments here's what I ended up with:

```
def get_concrete_name_of_class(klass):
    """Given a class return the concrete name of the class.

    klass - The reference to the class we're interested in.

    Raises a `TypeError` if klass is not a class.
    """

    if not isinstance(klass, (type, ClassType)):
        raise TypeError('The klass argument must be a class. Got type %s; %s' % (type(klass), klass))

    return '%s.%s' % (klass.__module__, klass.__name__)
```

Comment: This is contrived and silly.  The `type` and `issubclass` functions will tell you everything you're asking.  Why not use them?

Comment: @S.Lott:  Sorry if you felt it was contrived and silly.  And `type` and `issubclass` will not tell me the full path to class, which was my main question.

Comment: What do you mean by "full path"?

Comment: @sdolan: To avoid writing problems that seem contrived, it helps to explain *what* you're tying to do.  In this case, there seems to be no purpose behind this.  Providing some reason why you want to know this can help us solve your **real** problem rather than hack around with obscure (and useless) Python trivia.

Comment: @S.Lott: Thanks for the feedback on writing better questions.  My real reason behind this is I'm creating a Django model field to store classes in the db.  And in full path I mean 'django.form.CharField' rather than just 'CharField'.

Comment: @sdolan: If "Full Math" means `"Module"."Classname"`, then you should update your question to explain that you mean.  What you're doing makes very little sense since classes are more easily stored in .pyc files and instances are usually stored in a database.

Comment: @S.Lott: I've updated to question title to include that.  I've created the custom model for so I can do `MyModel.objects.create(field_class = CharField)`.  The `CharField` class gets translated into "django.forms.CharField" and stored as a string in the database.  When I access my models' `field_class` attribute it takes the "django.forms.CharField" string and converts in back to the `django.forms.CharField` class before returning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using `klass.__name__`, or to get the fully qualified name, `klass.__module__+'.'+klass.__name__`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just say

```
klass.__module__ + "." + klass.__name__
```

As for how to determine whether something is an old class or new class, I recommend saying something like

```
from types import ClassType  # old style class type

if not isinstance(klass, (type, ClassType)):
    # not a class
elif isinstance(klass, type):
    # new-style class
else:
    # old-style class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class X:
...     pass
... 
>>> class Y( object ):
...     pass
...
```

The type function tells you if a name is a class and old-style vs. new style.

```
>>> type(X)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(Y)
<type 'type'>
```

It also tells you what an object is.

```
>>> x= X()
>>> type(x)
<type 'instance'>
>>> y= Y()
>>> type(y)
<class '__main__.Y'>
```

You can test old-stye vs. new style by simply asking what it's a subclass of.

```
>>> issubclass(y.__class__,object)
True
>>> issubclass(x.__class__,object)
False
>>>
```